# Is there any way to control the Windows Zoom feature using the mouse wheel?

Tags: windows, windows-11, zoom

Is there any way to control the Windows Zoom feature using the mouse wheel?
The current Zoom UI is kind of klunky, requiring you to click and click to increase in increments, rather than a smooth zoom, similar to Mac.
[image]

Comment: What if you hold ctrl + scroll the wheel?

Comment: Maybe You can use `win` + `+`, it's easier that way. Or if you need to do it with a mouse, remapping a mouse like told [here](https://youtu.be/hC58JH7QaSs)  will be needed.